# How do you deal with concurrency in NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate

How do you support optimistic / pessimistic concurrency using NHibernate?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

NHibernate, by default, supports optimistic concurrency. Pessimistic concurrency, on the other hand, can be accomplished through the `ISession.Lock()` method.

These issues are discussed in detail in [this document](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#transactions).

Comment: Transactions and Concurrency docs now here: http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#transactions

Answer (score 22):

NHibernate supports 2 types of optimistic concurrency.

You can either have it check dirty fields by using "optimistic-lock=dirty" attribute on the "class" element in your mapping files or you can use "optimistic-lock=version" (which is also the default).  If you are using version you need to provide a "version" element in your mapping file that maps to a field in your database.

Version can be of type Int64, Int32, Int16, Ticks, Timestamp, or TimeSpan and are automatically incremented on save.  See [Chapter 5](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping) in the NHibernate documentation for more info.

Answer (score 2):

You can also 'just' manually compare the version numbers (assuming you've added a Version property to your entity).

Clearly Optimistic is the only sane option. Sometimes of course, we have to deal with crazy scenarios however...