# Abstract Base class for All Domain Entity Objects

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

I am seeing in some domain object models that an abstract base class is created(that implement Equals and GetHashCode) for all domain Entity objects to inherit from to gain their identity.

I am not clear why this base class is needed and when and why it should be used. Can you provide me some insight on this or refer me a link that talks on this

Thanks

Now I understand the advantages of overriding Equality (this link helped http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_Canonical_Forms—Identity_Equality)

Going back to domain driven design I would like to expand my question a bit;

I have a customer entity which I use guid as identity.

If I create 2 instances of customer with exactly the same details, since I am using guid as the identity they will be two different objects. But as they have all attributes the same they should be the same object(or is it a better ddd practice to keep them unique and seperate??)

Trying to understand if I should handle the equality of two objects by their full attribute value match. If I go toward that direction then I am looking at either overriding the Equality of the base class on the level of sub class and implement these conditions or have the identity of the entity a string or hash code(?) representation of the values of all these attributes and use the Equality of the base class.

I could be little off here so thanks in advance for the patience.

Comment: Please provide details of what you're referring to. You're not seeing some industry-wide practice that everyone knows about -  you're more likely seeing something specific to the details you're not providing us!

Comment: hope this is better - I was not clear though where I should post a second question as a follow up to this question so I just placed it in by editing my original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of the term **equality** is overloaded here:

1) Equality for *Identity*

If you have 2 instances of the same Customer, they should both have the same GUID value – it’s the only way to ensure that you're working with the same Entity.  In reality, there will always be different instances of the same Entity (e.g. multi-user apps running on different machines).

2) Equality for *sameness*

This is where you're checking that 2 instances have all the same values.  For instance, if 2 staff members are looking at the same Customer, and the first person modifies & saves it, both people will see different data.  They’re both interested in the same Customer, but the data becomes stale.

For (2), you definitely need a mechanism to do the checking.  You could compare each property (expensive), or you could use a ‘version’ property to detect changes (see [NHibernate’s optimistic locking mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118526/how-do-you-deal-with-concurrency-in-nhibernate)).

I think your example is a bit contrived, and might be drawing you away from the more important aspects of DDD.  If you’re interested, [I sell a tool](http://www.evolving-software.co.uk) that can help grasp DDD concepts easier.

Answer (score 2):

You should compare the IDs of the objects if they are entities and their attributes in case they are value objects. That means that you don't have to inherit your value objects from a base entity, but for entities it's better to create one.

How to understand if a class is an entity or a value object? You should answer a question: are objects of such class equal if they have the same attribute set? If yes, they are values objects. For example, two persons are not equal even if they have the same names and birth dates - you should treat them as different entities anyway. But if you have 25 cent coin, you probably don't care what **exact** piece of metal do you have, they all just 25 cent coins.

There's a great article describing the details: [domain object base class](http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2014/11/08/domain-object-base-class/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are following DDD, I believe you should check on the equality of the objects by their ID (Identity). This is because domain entities are primary defined and tracked by its identity and not by attributes. So no matter how similar they are with other objects, they are still diffirent entities.

Another concept that you would want to check out is a value object. It is something that describes a charasteristics of an object and doesn't require an identity. Example would be, address, money, color.

Answer (score 0):

You pointed at two of the reasons of why it is used.

For Equals you may not want to always check if the actual reference is equal, because it may not be.  You may want to use some sort of identifying property (like public int ID) to check against to see if 2 entities are equal.  The base implementation of Equals is just going to check if the 2 references are equal.

As far as hash code it's a way to uniquely identify a given object/type when using it in hash algorithms etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would have equals only check on identity, because it allows you to have an instance of an entity containing a before and after situation, which can be very handy at times. To check if an instance has changed, a Dirty flag can do the trick.

HTH,
Jonathan