# How to make objects thread safe with Nhibernate

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have multiple threads making sometimes rapid SaveOrUpdate of the same object graph using NHibernate. I use currently "session per request", at least I think I do (?). Some times I get the exception:

> StaleObjectStateException 
>   Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect):

My programs load the complete database at startup in order to maintain a complete runtime entity, and then makes only SaveOrUpdate operations, and in rare occasion a Delete operation. These are not typical user-interaction programs, but robots running on remote events like financial market data.

Are there some obvious design flaws/poor practice with this that may explain the stale states?

Repository:

```
    public class GenericRepository<T>
    {

        public IList<T> GetAll()
        {
            using (ISession session = FnhManager.OpenSession())
            {
                var instances = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T)).List<T>();
                return instances;
            }
        }

        public void SaveOrUpdate(IList<T> instances)
        {

            if (instances != null)
            {
                using (ISession session = FnhManager.OpenSession())
                {
                    using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            foreach (var i in instances)
                            {
                                session.SaveOrUpdate(i);
                            }
                            transaction.Commit();

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            transaction.Rollback();     
                            Trace.TraceError("GenericRepository.SaveOrUpdate IList<" + typeof(T).ToString() + ">" , ex.ToString());
                            throw;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
//...
```

FnhManager:

```
public class FnhManager
{

    private static Configuration cfg;
    private static ISessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private static string connectionString;


    private FnhManager(){}


    public static ISession OpenSession()
    {
        return sessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Pass Any map class, used to locate all maps.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TAnyMap"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="path"></param>
    /// <param name="DbFileName"></param>
    /// <remarks></remarks>
    public static void ConfigureSessionFactory<TAnyMap>(string path, string DbFileName, DatabaseType type)
    {

        connectionString = "Data Source=" + Path.Combine(path, DbFileName);

        switch (type)
        {
            case DatabaseType.SqlCe:
                sessionFactory = CreateSessionFactorySqlCe<TAnyMap>(path,DbFileName);
                break;

            case DatabaseType.SQLite:
                sessionFactory = CreateSessionFactorySQLite<TAnyMap>();
                break;
        }

    }

    private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactorySQLite<TMap>()
    {

        Trace.TraceInformation("Creating SessionFactory SQLite for: " + connectionString);

        try
        {
            var fluentConfiguration = Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(connectionString))
                .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<TMap>()
                   .Conventions.Add(FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Helpers.DefaultLazy.Never()))
                   .ExposeConfiguration(c => cfg = c)
                   .Cache(c => c.UseQueryCache());

            sessionFactory = fluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory();

            return sessionFactory;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.TraceError("Create SessionFactory Exception: " + ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }


    }

    private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactorySqlCe<TMap>( string dbPath, string dbName )
    {

        //Must add SqlCe dll x86+amd64-folders to bin folder.  !!! 

        FileInfo f = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(dbPath, dbName));
        if (!f.Exists)
        {
            var engine = new SqlCeEngine(connectionString);
            engine.CreateDatabase();
        }

        var fluentConfiguration = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlCeConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString( s => s.Is(connectionString)))
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<TMap>()
                .Conventions.Add(FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Helpers.DefaultLazy.Never()))
               .ExposeConfiguration(c => cfg = c)
                .Cache(c => c.UseQueryCache());
        sessionFactory = fluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory();

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void BuildDatabaseFromSchema()
    {
        SchemaExport e = new SchemaExport(cfg);
        e.Execute(false, true, false);
    }


    public static void ValidateDatabase()
    {

        SchemaValidator validator = new SchemaValidator(cfg);

        try
        {
            validator.Validate();
        }
        catch (HibernateException ex)
        {
            // not valid, try to update
            try
            {

                SchemaUpdate update = new SchemaUpdate(cfg);
                update.Execute(false, true);

            }
            catch (HibernateException e)
            {
                Trace.TraceError("Invalid schema. HibernateException: ", ex.ToString());
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Invalid schema: Exception: (Should not occur) " + ex.ToString);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for my bad english and may complicated explanation.
But I try it again:

```
MyDomain first = MyDomainDao.Load(1);

MyDomain second = MyDomainDao.Load(1);

first.Name = "juhe";

MyDomainDao.SaveOrUpdate(first);

// Throws an exception, because the 'second' is not 'refreshed'

MyDomainDao.SaveOrUpdate(second);
```

If your code is like this you got this problem. This loadings can be in diffrent threads, now the object has two diffrent states within every session.

Whats about you versioning the domain object?
I do not exactly know your implementation, but try to refresh your entity:

```
 Session.Refresh(myDomain, LockMode.None)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the scope of object-relational mapping there are two main approaches for concurrency control, [Optimistic and Pessimistic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213031%28v=sql.80%29.aspx), which are usually implemented in the application data access layer.

Under Optimistic concurrency control your application doesn't expect that the same database entity will be updated simultaneously, so multiple threads are allowed to access it concurrently without any locking. However, if two threads are caught trying to update the same version of a database entity, one of them will be forced to rollback the operation, otherwise one's update would overwrite the other's.

[Nhibernate's default approach is Optimistic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118526/how-do-you-deal-with-concurrency-in-nhibernate), and in the case conflicting updates occur the **StaleObjectStateException** you observed is thrown.

If you find that the Optimistic concurrency control is not enough for your needs, you can use [NHibernate's Pessimistic Locking mechanism](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#transactions-locking) to acquire an exclusive lock on a database entity for the duration of an entire transaction.

Comment: Thanks, but will those locks have any effect when my updates happen on different sessions?  I imagine my problem is three object states; A, B(1st update), C(2nd update), then two calls are made rapidly; AtoB and BtoC, then for the last call, the session expects AtoWhatever, since first update session is not completed, but receives BtoSomething.. Though it's hard to understand since I don't know how NHibernate identifies previous state of an object it receives, so that may be wrong hypothesis..?

Comment: Pessimistic locking is intended to work on different sessions, and depending on your database provider it is implemented down to the SQL level.

Answer (score 0):

The exception occurs because you load an object twice (or more) and save the first in "State A" and the second in "State B". So, NHibernate will check if the states are the same. The Object with "State B" does no more exists (because of deletion) or in your case, it is updated!

Comment: This is not very clear to me. First I load only once, and keep only one runtime entity object graph. But is the stale state occurring because two sessions are opened just after each other with different object states before the first completes? I tried to put a lock on a common repository SaveOrUpdate method, but that didn't help.